# magento add global_messages to cms page with cms directive

Tags: magento, content-management-system, block, message

I've tried the following in a cms page :

```
{{block type="core/messages" template="core/messages.phtml"}}
{{block type="core/messages" as="global_messages"}}
{{block type="Mage_core_Block_Messages" template="core/messages.phtml"}}
```

but none worked. I'd like to display

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess('Your form has been sent');
```

in a cms page to which the controller redirects.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the messages must be passed to the message block from storage. This is typically done in the controller action (ref [`Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::_initLayoutMessages()`](https://github.com/LokeyCoding/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php#L636)).

It would be quite simple to rewrite the `Mage_Cms_PageController` class to include this method call (for general utility) or to use an observer for individual cases.

Comment: Can you explain a little bit please ? where should initLayoutMessages() be called ?
Or what use of observer should be done else ?

Comment: I've rewritten cms_pagecontroller and added :
`$this->_initLayoutMessages('core/session');`
right before rendering the cms page, but nothing appears...

Comment: Try removing those CMS directives :-)

Comment: Also: you need to call `addSuccess()` in the form handling script, in case that's not apparent.

Comment: How is supposed to appear the messages block if I remove the cms directives ?

addSuccess() is called from the controller handling the form, then a redirect is called to the cms page.

Comment: Should I also rewrite the cms template content.phtml or another one ?

Comment: Aha! It's only `global_messages` which is called in root templates. Try adding this to your page's layout updates (not content area): `<reference name="content"><action method="setChild"><block>messages</block></action></reference>`

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. In what file ? can you give the filename please ? I may use global_messages : how to add a string to global_messages ?

Comment: Not a file. When editing the CMS page you can add layout XML in the page content tab.

Comment: not working... I'm discouraged. I've modified the destination redirect (/, /checkout/cart, etc), and the other pages dont display the message neither. Maybe addSuccess() is not working as expected.

Comment: What about customer/session ? by the way what is the difference between core and customer session ?